# Jenkins - Trigger different plugins at different times independent of build

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins

Is it possible to have multiple plugins which are doing different jobs and triggered at different time **independent of build** - when build is pressed plugins do not trigger?

My current problem is that Jenkins is triggering plugins everytime build is pressed. I need to trigger it only at specific time.

I have tried Build Triggers - Schedule and [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) but with no success.

Comment: Can you please clarify what exactly you are trying to do?

Comment: I am using [Publish Over SSH Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Publish+Over+SSH+Plugin) for deploying binary files. Problem occurs that plugin is trigged always when build is pressed. I want to deploy only daily at midnight.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [Run Condition Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Run+Condition+Plugin). Make the publishing build step conditional on a build parameter (let's name it *DO_PUBLISH*). Set that parameter to *FALSE* by default, so when the build is started by hand the publishing step is not triggered.

Now, create an auxiliary build that is scheduled to run daily at midnight and calls your main build via [Parameterized Trigger Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Parameterized+Trigger+Plugin) with *DO_PUBLISH* parameter set to *TRUE* like this:

Let's say your build is called *MY-BUILD*. Create a new build *TRIGGER-MY-BUILD*. In *Build Triggers*  check *Build Periodically* and enter *Schedule* (`@daily` or `0 0 * * *`).

Install *Parameterized Trigger* plugin. Click on *Add Build Step* -> select *Trigger/call builds on other projects* -> enter *MY-BUILD* in *Projects to build* -> *Add Parameters* -> choose *Predefined Parameters* -> enter `DO_PUBLISH=TRUE` in *Parameters* edit box.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I have been able to create the first step. Is second step telling me to set daily trigger in Build Triggers - Schedule? And how to call it via Trigger Plugin?

Comment: (1) Yes - *Build Triggers* - check *Build Periodically* - enter *Schedule*. (2) I'll edit the answer.

Comment: I tried your option, but was still unable to make it work. Which condition should I choose at _Run?_ I tried another option - set _Run?_ condition to Time and set values for _Earliest_, _Latest_ and _Schedule_ at daily. It is working, but the problem is that it is building over and over again. It does not stop once the build is triggered.

Comment: In *MY-BUILD* you choose *Conditional Step (single)* -> *Boolean Condition* at *Run?* and *${DO\_PUBLISH}* as *Token*. You then specify SSH Publish as *Builder*. In *TRIGGER-MY-BUILD* you do not use the conditional step.